# Controlling how parameters are sent to superclass constructor from subclass constructor declaration (C++)

Tags: c++

Can it be done?  I am looking for something different than using the member initialization list (because that is present in the definition, not necessarily the declaration).

Something like

```
class(args) : superclass(fn of args);
```

Comment: I think you're going to need to restate your question more clearly.

Comment: maybe an example of what you whant to do? some pseudocode ?

Comment: Declaration declares how something should be used (interface).
Definition defines what happens when it is used.
Therefore, what you ask belongs in the definition.
Explain why do you want it in declaration and you could get a better  solution.

Comment: I still don't see why the initializer list isn't sufficient. If your problem is with the subclasses using the wrong constructors, remove them.

Comment: What arguments the superclass is going to receive seems to me to be something you'd want to define in an interface....on par with arguments the constructor the subclass takes.

Comment: The base class' constructor declaration takes care of only the types being passed that you want - how is that unsufficient?

Comment: Because the base might have more than a default constructor, in which case you would not know which constructor is going to be called.

Comment: @drenami: Stop trying to debate about how you think things should work and try a describe your problem better (as the requested by the hugely up voted comment above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking makes no sense.

In C++ each class has a constructor.
For a constructor the declaration defines the parameters.
For a constructor the definition defines how the parameters are used (like how they are passed to the base class).

Example:

```
Plop.h
=============
class Point
{
    public:
       Point(int x,int y);
};

class MyPoint: public Point
{
    public:
        MyPoint(int x);
        MyPoint(int x,int y);
        MyPoint(double z);
};

Plop.cpp
========
Point::Point(int x,int y)
{}

MyPoint::MyPoint(int x):       Point(x,x)           {}
MyPoint::MyPoint(int x,int y): Point(x*2,y-x)       {}
MyPoint::MyPoint(double z):    Point(sin(z),cos(z)) {}
```

Comment: So if I have both a header file (.h) and a definition file (.cpp), I cannot use what you just did?

Comment: @drenami: Yes you can. But maybe if you explain what your problem is slightly better, then we can find a better way to explain it.

Comment: Not how I wanted to do it, but like you alluded to, it's pointless to debate my conception of declaration versus reality.

Answer (score 0):

What forbid you from using member functions?

Comment: The fact that virtual functions almost certainly don't work the way you think they do with a partially constructed object?